# CDO.Message encoding issue

Tags: encoding, utf-8, vbscript

We're currently changing our mail delivery system to use solely `UTF-8`.

There seems to be a problem with the sender name, when the email contains non ASCII chars (hebrew) the subject & body render ok, but the sender name, as it appears in my gmail account, becomes - `??????`.

There is a line of code:

```
myMail.BodyPart.Charset = "UTF-8"
```

So I thought there should be some code of the like:

```
myMail.SenderName.Charset = "UTF-8"
```

But I can't seem to find the right code to use, assuming this would do the trick.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526453%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx). If what you want isn't in there, it's probably not supported.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: http://www.powerasp.net/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp

```
Dim ObjSendMail
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "myserver"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

ObjSendMail.To = to_email
ObjSendMail.Subject = subject
ObjSendMail.From = from_email

'ObjSendMail.TextBody = mensaje   'tipo texto
ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = mensaje   'tipo html

ObjSendMail.TextBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"  'support symbols á ñ ¡

ObjSendMail.Send

Set ObjSendMail = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

With iMsg
    .BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `HTMLBody` then:

```
ObjSendMail.HTMLBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```